# WebAPI with Lazy Loading

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I was following a tutorial from Pluralsight called "Building Web Apps & Services with Entity Framework and Web API".  I followed the tutorial but started getting errors when trying to return my entity framework objects.
The objects had been set up with lazy loading.  I have two kinds of objects - Projects and ProjectTasks.  I liked the idea of being able to lazy load and have one web api method that would get the projects without the details of the project tasks and another that would get the list of projects with the details of the project tasks associated.

However whenever I tried to call the methods it would throw an error that there was already an open data reader.  When I looked into this it was because the API was triggering the lazy load to serialize the content and was trying to use multiple data readers in the background.  In the tutorial he never showed the config file with the connection string but the only way I could make this work was to turn on multiple active result sets.  When I looked into what that did  though I saw there could be negative consequences to using it.

I call: http://localhost:51362/api/Projects/GetAllProjects

So now I just always include the details as below. :

```
    public IQueryable<Project> GetAllProjects()
    {
        return db.Projects;
    }
```

And here is the Controller Action:

```
public IQueryable<Project> Get()
{
     var projects = repository.GetAllProjects();
     return projects;
}
```

What I had before was:

```
    public IQueryable<Project> GetAllProjects()
    {
        return db.Projects;
    }

    public IQueryable<Project> GetAllProjectsWithDetails()
    {
        return db.Projects.Include("ProjectTasks.ProjectTaskItems");
    }
```

The virtual functions for Entity framework is what I was reading causes the issues.

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

    public decimal EstimatedCost { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectTask> ProjectTasks { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectTask
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ProjectTaskName { get; set; }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectTaskItem> ProjectTaskItems { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectTaskItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ProjectTaskItemName { get; set; }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    public virtual ProjectTask ProjectTask { get; set; }

}
```

Repository:

```
public class ProjectTrackingRepository : IProjectTrackingRepository
{
    private GentrifyAPIContext db;

    public ProjectTrackingRepository(GentrifyAPIContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public IQueryable<Project> GetAllProjects()
    {
        return db.Projects.Include("ProjectTasks.ProjectTaskItems"); ;
    }

    public IQueryable<Project> GetAllProjectsWithDetails()
    {
        return db.Projects.Include("ProjectTasks.ProjectTaskItems");
    }

    public Project GetProject(int id)
    {
        return db.Projects.Include("ProjectTasks.ProjectTaskItems").FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
    }
}
```

One thing I had looked at was converting to a list and returning an IEnumerable instead of IQueryable.  However I wasn't sure if I'd be losing some functionality by not using IQueryable.

I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.  In the plural sight videos he uses this code and it works - but for me it doesn't - seems like MARS had to be turned on.

Here is the error:

```
{  
   "$id":"1",
   "message":"An error has occurred.",
   "exceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
   "exceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException",
   "stackTrace":null,
   "innerException":{  
      "$id":"2",
      "message":"An error has occurred.",
      "exceptionMessage":"Error getting value from 'ProjectTasks' on 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Project_B44D8796492C46C82F9FF2D753EAC55E7477B5DA96A20EA9E1390986A5A4553E'.",
      "exceptionType":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException",
      "stackTrace":"   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()",
      "innerException":{  
         "$id":"3",
         "message":"An error has occurred.",
         "exceptionMessage":"An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.",
         "exceptionType":"System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException",
         "stackTrace":"   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty[TItem](TItem propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<GetInterceptorDelegate>b__1(TProxy proxy, TItem item)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Project_B44D8796492C46C82F9FF2D753EAC55E7477B5DA96A20EA9E1390986A5A4553E.get_ProjectTasks()\r\n   at GetProjectTasks(Object )\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)",
         "innerException":{  
            "$id":"4",
            "message":"An error has occurred.",
            "exceptionMessage":"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.",
            "exceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException",
            "stackTrace":"   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute(String method, SqlCommand command)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your usage.

Comment: I edited to include the URL call I was making and the respository that is being used.

Comment: Ohhh. Ok. First. You should not return IQueryable in controller. IQueryable means deferred execution. It doesn't make much sense here. Second. You should not return Entity Framework classes in API controllers. API should have its own classes. Third. How do you expect Web API to serialize your objects to XML/JSON? There are circular references between objects, so you may end up in stack overflow (not Stack Overflow).

Comment: So from what I read Newtonsoft JSON.NET handles the circular references problem.  It actually does work correctly when I do the eager loading.  I did have a feeling I needed new model classes and maybe make a project for my models without the EF references.  The tutorial does end up using Breeze so I am working through that now.  I did figure maybe I should just return an IEnumerable or something though and that would solve the issue.

Comment: Not entirely. Your controller should return a model suited to the method's purpose, *not* entities. Even if you do a .ToList() the issue you will repeatedly face is with lazy load references. GetAllProjects().ToList() will avoid the issue with IQueryable of Project, but if Projects have other dependencies (I.e Project.Subjects, Project.Students, etc.) each of these have to be fetched as well. From your API point of view define a model for the data structure you want to return as a POCO, then populate that structure within the service with a .Select() from your entities.